# Работа с несколькими репозиториями в одной ViewModel на kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, viewmodel

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильней сделать так, чтоб ViewModel поддерживала работу с нужным репозиторием в зависимости от параметра?
Android приложение должно выводить список заявок, заявки бывают разных типов. Соответственно хочу использовать один фрагмент для разных типов и в одной модели универсально работать с репозиторием, который будет вытягивать из базы (Room) заявки нужного типа.

Сделал общий интерфейс для репозиториев:

```
interface RequestRepository<T> {

    fun getRequests(): LiveData<List<T>>

    fun getRequestById(requestId: String): LiveData<T>

    suspend fun insertRequests(requests: List<T>)

    suspend fun deleteRequest(request: T)

    suspend fun deleteAllRequests()

}
```

Один из репозиториев:

```
class PaymentRequestRepository private constructor(private val paymentRequestDao: PaymentRequestDao) : RequestRepository<PaymentRequest> {

    override fun getRequests() = paymentRequestDao.getRequests()

    override fun getRequestById(requestId: String) = paymentRequestDao.getRequestById(requestId)

    override suspend fun insertRequests(requests: List<PaymentRequest>) {
        paymentRequestDao.deleteAll()
        paymentRequestDao.insertAll(requests)
    }

    override suspend fun deleteRequest(request: PaymentRequest) = paymentRequestDao.delete(request)

    override suspend fun deleteAllRequests() = paymentRequestDao.deleteAll()

    companion object {

        // For Singleton instantiation
        @Volatile private var instance: PaymentRequestRepository? = null

        fun getInstance(paymentRequestDao: PaymentRequestDao) =
            instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                instance ?: PaymentRequestRepository(paymentRequestDao).also { instance = it }
            }
    }

}
```

Как в ViewModel работать с нужным репозиторием в зависимости от типа заявки?

```
class RequestListViewModel(application: Application, val requestType: RequestType): AndroidViewModel(application) {

    //lateinit var paymentRequestRepository: PaymentRequestRepository
    //lateinit var serviceRequestRepository: ServiceRequestRepository
    lateinit var requestRepository: RequestRepository<BaseRequestDao<Request>>

    ...

    init {
        val database = AgreementsDatabase.getDatabase(application)

        when (requestType) {
            RequestType.MONEY -> {
                val paymentRequestDao = database.paymentRequestsDao()
                requestRepository = PaymentRequestRepository.getInstance(paymentRequestDao)
            }
            RequestType.SERVICE -> {
                val serviceRequestDao = database.serviceRequestsDao()
                requestRepository = ServiceRequestRepository.getInstance(serviceRequestDao)
            }
            RequestType.DELIVERY -> {
                val deliveryRequestsDao = database.deliveryRequestsDao()
                requestRepository = DeliveryRequestRepository.getInstance(deliveryRequestsDao)
            }
        }
        _requests = requestRepository.getRequests()

        updateRequests();
    }
}
```

**При создании репозитория получаю ошибку несовпадения типов:**

**requestRepository = PaymentRequestRepository.getInstance(paymentRequestDao)**

Подскажите как это правильно делается?

Comment: Ошибку покажите, не понятно без логов

Comment: Да ошибку то и показать толком не могу. Просто не знаю как сделать переменную общего интерфейсного типа  и ее инициализировать экземпляром требуемого в данном случае репозитория.
Понимаю что некрасиво использовать кучу отдельных переменных под репозиторий каждого типа, но как по другому сделать не знаю.

Comment: В это случае должен быть тип RequestRepository для переменной requestRepository

Comment: Вы что-то не то делаете, у вас в списке все равно используются разные холдеры, вам проще сделать наследников от базового фрагмента со списком и установить адаптер для нужного типа

Comment: Во фрагменте списка я решил использовать общий адаптер для разных типов заявок, в адаптер передаю layout и Id binding-переменной:
 `when (args.requestType) {
  RequestType.MONEY -> {
   requestListLayoutId = R.layout.payment_request_list_item
   requestBindingId = BR.request
  }
  RequestType.SERVICE -> {
   requestListLayoutId = R.layout.service_request_list_item
   requestBindingId = BR.serviceRequest
  }
  ...
 }
 val adapter = RequestsAdapter(requestListLayoutId, requestBindingId, RequestsAdapter.OnClickListener{viewModel.showRequest(it)})`

Comment: Моя проблема в том, что для создания репозитория мне нужно ему передать одну из реализаций DAO, а указать в конструкторе параметр с типом интерфейса BaseRequestDao<Request>(его реализуют все мои dao-шки) не выходит.
Видимо я что-то перемудрил.

Comment: Не рекомедую смешивать разные типы в одном в одном адаптере, вам потом это ещё поддерживать

Comment: Ну в данном случае от списка требуется только отобразить поля конкретной заявки, биндинг вроде решает эту проблему, поэтому и решил обойтись единой реализацией адаптера, иначе получилось бы просто три абсолютно одинаковых реализации адаптера.

С репозиторием не получилось сделать универсально, решил сделать общий интерфейс для ViewModel и вынести особенности работы с конкретным репозиторием в отдельные реализации этой модели, а в фабрике, которая будет создавать модель, уже в зависимости от параметра выбирать необходимую реализацию viewModel.

Comment: Но теперь столкнулся с тем, что хочется чтобы у всех ViewModel было одно LiveData-поле на которое я бы подписывался и получал из него заявки нужного типа. Не могу сохранить в MutableLiveData<List<Request>> данные конкретного типа MutableLiveData<List<PaymentRequest>>.
Я еще новичок в kotlin и android.)

Comment: Почитайте о Transformations. Там есть вариант как привести два разных варианта ответов к одному ливдата.

Comment: Спасибо! Обязательно посмотрю.